# Update record in EF not working as expected

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to update a record with EF in a WebAPI PUT controller. I am using the following code

```
        Product dbProduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(s => s.InternalReferenceId == InternalReferenceId && s.SupplierId == SupplierId);

    if (dbProduct != null)
    {
        db.Products.Attach(dbProduct);
        var entry = db.Entry(dbProduct);
        entry.Property(e => e.Description).IsModified = true;

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok();
```

The product is found, as it returns 200 Ok. But nothing gets updated. I am currently just trying to get the description updated.

I am calling `api.com/api/products/update?InternalReferenceId=1&SupplierId=1` and it, as mentioned, finds a record. In the PUT request, i have the following

```
{
  "description": "testing 123"
}
```

Why wont it update?

Comment: you're getting the `entity` and attaching it as it is without assigning new value of `Description`.

Comment: How would that look? This line works 'dbProducts.Description = product.Description;', but then what is the point of attach, getting the entry and set ismodified?

Comment: You should send a new object of your `entity class` with `ID` and `updated values` and then attach that object to your `dbContext`.

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that. I only have the Id, after i look it up based on internalrefId and supplierId, as seen in my code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the entity and attaching it as it is without assigning new value of Description. Try this with your existing code:

```
Product dbProduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(s => s.InternalReferenceId == InternalReferenceId && s.SupplierId == SupplierId);

if (dbProduct != null)
{
    dbProduct.Description = "testing 123";
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
else
{
    return NotFound();
}

return Ok();
```

But the best way go would be:

1. Send the updated object of entity in `body` of `PUT` request with `ID` and value of `updated column`.
2. Receive object using`[FromBody]` and attach it your context.
3. `SaveChanges`.

Something like this:

```
public bool Put([FromBody]Product updatedProduct)
{
  db.Products.Attach(updatedProduct);
  var entry = db.Entry(updatedProduct);
  entry.Property(e => e.Description).IsModified = true;

  return db.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

and your JSON would look like:

```
{
  "ProductID": 1, //id of your record to be updated.
  "InternalReferenceId": 1,
  "SupplierId": 1,
  "Description": "testing 123"
}
```

The approach you want to follow requires the `object` of entity with at least its original `ID` of database so that you can directly attach it to your `dbContext`. If you can't send the `object` in `body` of `request` then you don't need these line:

```
db.Products.Attach(dbProduct);
var entry = db.Entry(dbProduct);
entry.Property(e => e.Description).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: Why make a new entity (updatedProduct). Why not just use the entity "dbProduct"?

Comment: Yes, but i do not, and will not, have the ProductID. In this special case, it is simply not possible

Comment: then you should go with the first `code snippet` in the answer. you don't need to attach `entity` again, just set the updated values and call `SaveChanges()`

Comment: Cool, thank you for the help and the well described answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code :-

```
var dbProduct = db.Products.FirstOrDefault(s => s.InternalReferenceId == InternalReferenceId && s.SupplierId == SupplierId);

        if (dbProduct != null)
        {
            dbProduct.Description="Bla Bla Bla ";
            db.Products.Attach(dbProduct);
            var entry = db.Entry(dbProduct);
            entry.Property(e => e.Description).IsModified = true;

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok();
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But then it also works if i just add "dbProduct.Description="Bla Bla Bla ";" and remove "db.Products.Attach(dbProduct);
            var entry = db.Entry(dbProduct);
            entry.Property(e => e.Description).IsModified = true;". So what is the point of the these 3 lines. What are they doing?

Answer (score 0):

As you are working in Connected mode of Entity framework there is no need to use Attach method, in this default mode when you get an object from database Entity framework will store the state of object and when you call method SaveChanges() Entity framework will compare the state of object and apply the changes. We use Attach when we are working in disconnect mode. In that case we need to give the state of object to Entity framework by using Attach.

Comment: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/attach-disconnected-entity-graph.aspx